# Sagepay Protocol 3 Templates & Languages

Tags: php, opayo

We are looking to implement Sagepay's protocol 3 with their templates and multi-language support.  Can I find anything to give me a clue as to how you make it multi-lingual, and the documentation doesn't say either?

Has anyone done it yet?

Answer (score 0):

Multi languages are supported through the browser.

The Custom Template kit is available to use via Sage Pay website for you to customise - http://www.sagepay.com/help/downloads/581

Open the XSLT file to locate the i18n file. Within there you can add the languages whereby an example is detailed below. The [...] is used to omit all the additional text lables:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<multi-lingual-text>
    -
    <texts xml:lang="en">
        <text label="address_file">addresspop.htm</text>
        <text label="amount">Amount :</text>
        […]
        <text label="clientemail_anyquestion_sagepay_part4"> directly.</text>
        <text label="show_more_payments">Show more payment types.</text>
    </texts>

    <texts xml:lang="es">
        <text label="address_file">addresspop.htm</text>
        <text label="amount">Cantidad:</text>
        […]
        <text label="clientemail_anyquestion_sagepay_part4"> directamente.</text>
        <text label="show_more_payments">Mostrar más tipos de pago.</text>
    </texts>

    <texts xml:lang="de">
        <text label="address_file">addresspop.htm</text>
        <text label="amount">Betrag :</text>
        […]
        <text label="clientemail_anyquestion_sagepay_part4"> direkt.</text>
        <text label="show_more_payments">Weitere Zahlungsarten anzeigen.</text>
    </texts>
</multi-lingual-text>
```

The i18n file will show the payment page in the same language as the browser language.

You could have an IF route to identify the language on the customers browser to bring up or call up the difference images/sheets.

You would also need to render the multi lingual buttons, referencing them so that dependant on the browser language used by the shopper, the correct buttons in the correct language populate on the website. The images are found within YourImages file.

You could amend the vsp3.css file - the stylesheet (i.e. the font, size, layout etc) can have vsp3., germanvsp3., spanishvsp3. etc.

If your template code works, if you submit the Custom Template file as a zip folder to templates@sagepay.com it can be uploaded. The zip would need to contain the xslt and images.

Hope this is helpful in some way.